# Retrieve note SourceUrl through ENNoteAdvanced

Tags: c#, .net, api, evernote

I would like to retrieve the URL associated with (some) Evernote notes, as seen in this screenshot:

[image: evernote-url]

#### Need for ENNoteAdvanced

After some digging, I found that the object `ENNoteAdvanced` has a property `SourceUrl` that should be exactly what I need.

However, I cannot find a way to download or cast an existing note as `ENNoteAdvanced`

#### Code for retrieving ENNote but how about ENNoteAdvanced

```
ENNote downloadedNote = sharedSession.DownloadNote(noteRef);
```

I fear the API only [allows creating new advanced notes for uploading](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-windows/blob/master/samples/CS/SampleAppAdvanced/SampleAppAdvanced/Program.cs), but does not allow working with existing downloaded notes as advanced notes?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, that was a shortcoming of the new Evernote Windows SDK.  So I just modified the SDK so as to support calling DownloadNote from the Advanced interface, which will return an ENNoteAdvanced instead of an ENNote.

In other words, do this:

```
ENSessionAdvanced.SetSharedSessionConsumerKey("your key", "your secret");
...[your code which authenticates, then gets you a valid noteRef]...
ENNoteAdvanced downloadedNote = ENSessionAdvanced.SharedSession.DownloadNote(noteRef);
Console.WriteLine(downloadedNote.SourceUrl);
```

The updated SDK [is available on Github now](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-windows).

Comment: Superb! However, when I just updated the [Evernote NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/evernote-cloud-sdk-windows/) then ENSessionAdvanced.SharedSession.DownloadNote still returns ENNote ?

Comment: What's the version number of the EvernoteSDK.dll in your project? It should be 1.0.7.0.

Comment: It is 1.0.7.0 indeed, but still returns ENNote. To double check, I cleaned my project and even deleted obj and bin directories and then rebuilt, but to no avail. So looked at the source code and looks like there is a small omission in your changes i.e. even though you instantiate ENNoteAdvanced on line 1703 the return type is still always ENNote on line 1680 - see https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-windows/blob/0dd25e435282fc3cd3001470f3294797e7f4d8aa/src/EvernoteSDK/ENSession.cs